# Tilde ( ~ ) syntax error (beginner / noob)

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, tilde

I am teaching myself python from Mike McGrath's 'python in easy steps' book. On the section talking about bitwise operators (| , &, ~, ^, >>, <<) it has you doing some moving of bits around. But when I try to use then tilde ~ I get a syntax error. But not for any of the other operators. Can someone please help a beginer and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
a = 10
b = 5
print('a =', a, '\tb=', b)

b = a ~ b

a = a ^ b
print('a=', a, '\tb=', b)
```

Comment: `~` is a thing you do to one number, not two.

Comment: In other words it's a [unary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_operation).

Comment: In the [Python 
docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations) you can find `~` in the section unary operators but not in the section binary operators.

Answer (score 0):

`~` is a unary operator, so `a ~ b` is a no go.